# GDB --init-command - import python class

Tags: python, gdb, gdbinit

I have a very minimal understanding of Python. I am also not too experienced with GDB. I'm trying to use GDB's `--init-command` flag to initialize some set up for me. I have two processors to debug which require setting up a JLink debug server. Since there's minor differences between the two, I wanted to create a class that would be imported by their respective init files. So Module1.init and Module2.init would import another file called Module.py which contains shared functions and a class to inherit from.

It looks something like the following.
Note: I've replaced some of the names and hid other information with `...` for confidentiality, but the structure is the same.
`Module.py`

```py
import os, sys, subprocess
import atexit

sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/.../libcxx-pretty-printers-master/src/')
from libcxx.v1.printers import register_libcxx_printers
register_libcxx_printers (None)

def handleSignals(e):
    if (not isinstance(e, gdb.SignalEvent)):
        return
    elif (e.stop_signal == 'SIGILL'):
        gdb.execute("continue")

class Module:
    ...

    def connectToDebugServer(self):
        gdb.execute(...)
```

`Module1.init` (which looks almost identical to `Module2.init` except for parameters

```py
python

import os, sys

sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/.../scripts/GDB/init/')
import Module

class Module1(Module.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(...)
    ...

inst = Module1()
inst.startDebugServer()
inst.connectToDebugServer()

end

set print pretty on
set print array on
set print demangle on
set print asm-demangle on
set print object on
```

I call these with `gdb --init-command=/path/to/Module1.init`. I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 15, in <module>
  File "C:/.../scripts/GDB/init\Module.py", line 49, in connectToDebugServer
    gdb.execute(...)
NameError: name 'gdb' is not defined
C:\...\scripts\GDB\init\Module1.init:21: Error in sourced command file:
Error while executing Python code.
```

When I call it instead like `gdb --init-command=/path/to/Module1.init --data-directory=/path/containing/Module1.init and Module.py/`, I get the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:/.../scripts/GDB/init\Module.py", line 5, in <module>
    from libcxx.v1.printers import register_libcxx_printers
  File "C:/.../scripts/GDB/lib/libcxx-pretty-printers-master/src\libcxx\v1\printers.py", line 19, in <module>
    import gdb
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gdb'
C:\...\scripts\GDB\init\Module1.init:21: Error in sourced command file:
Error while executing Python code.
```

Alternatively, if there is a way to pass arguments to an init file that would work too. That was my original idea but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `import gdb` in my `Module.py`.